# Cannot read json file downloaded from s3 bucket

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-s3

For context, I have a json file that I am reading in with the following code:

```
with open("file.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
```

Then, I modify this dict based on some other information:

```
for key in data:
    if key == label_file[-len(key):]:
        print(data)
        del data[key]
        print(data)
```

I know that this del call is actually working properly because I can see the actual json file being modified. Then, I update this file in the bucket through these lines

```
with open('file.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as updatedFile:
    json.dump(data, updatedFile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    s3.Bucket('bucket-name').upload_file(os.path.abspath('file.json'), 'file.json', ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "application/json"})
```

Reading the json file before updating the file works completely fine. Additionally, I can read from the json file if it is stored locally. However, in the case that I download the json file immediately from the bucket, the program crashes on `data = json.load(file)`.

Additionally, I've tried replacing the text in the downloaded json file with exactly what's in the local one, and it still crashes so I believe it is some file type issue with the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

This the code I use to read a json file from s3

```
    s3sr = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket_obj=s3sr.Bucket(bucket)
    obj = s3sc.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    data = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    jsondata = json.loads(data)
```